# How to change Kafka Broker Server Hardware safely?

Tags: apache-kafka

## ENV

- kafka 1.0.1

## Question

Hi, I have requirement to change Broker server hardware to new one.

**How can I safely move to the new broker server with data stored in the existing hardware?**
Is it okay to just copy the data to new broker server? Or is there any related migration tool?

Please let me know if there is a way or know-how to safely migrate to the new broker server. Thanks always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be "easy" or "very hard".

**DO not move the data from one machine to another**. It is not intented to do it that way.

The best scenario is automatic creation of topics is disabled.
In that case:

- If you can afford to have old and new hardware side-by-side for some time (say, no more than 1-2 days):

  - Add the new broker to the cluster (with a new ID).
  - List **ALL** the topics and partitions on the broker. You will need that.
  - Then, for each partition:

    - Move the partitions from the old hardware to the new (the [Kafka Partition assignment](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_partitionassignment) docs are awesome)
    - Start moving one or two replica partitions just to be sure the new hardware performs well and you create the JSON correctly.
    - Move partitions in batches, not one by one. Also do not move everything in one step. Start with a small set of partitions, then move more and more partitions.

Also, remember to check the new hardware performance is as good as the old one (in this cloud days it might not be true).

Comment: It's very safe solution but It can be a tedious job because i have many topics. 
Is there any way to change the broker without changing broker ID..?

Comment: Another question. Is there any problem if I can exchange the whole disk with a new device?